# Device detected as "mint"

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery, cyanogenmod

I'm using a xperia sp ( huashan ) device. Recently I read some tutorials and wanted to flash CM 11 M10 into the device. I rooted the device, then backed up the bootloader. Then unlocked it and installed the recovery kernel given in the following url.

[Custom Recovery Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2404452)

Then I used the following link to install CM11. I downloaded CM Rom from the official website for my device.

[CM Installation Tutorial](http://www.ibtimes.co.in/how-install-cyanogenmod-android-4-4-4-kitkat-cm11-m10-custom-rom-sony-xperia-sp-tutorial-610197)

When I go to CWM Recovery and try to install the zip file, it states the following message and stops the installation process.

> The zip is for devices C5303, C5302
>
> Device detected as 'mint'

I flashed my stock rom again and checked using flashtools the device it recognizes. My device is installed as C5303.

Any idea on fixing this issue.

Comment: Did you read through the full thread to make sure there weren't any updates or extra installation details. It sounds like there is wrong firmware/software in the ROM. Is it a nightly build?

Comment: it's not a nightly build! a snapshot for the xperia sp.

Answer (score 2):

CyanogenMod - Xperia SP maintainer here. If you are sure about having a Xperia SP then you can safely remove that assert check in the install script of the zip :)

you should have the right prop id so you can continue on with normal releases. i've never seen this issue before.

Comment: I removed the assert tag as it was mentioned in one of the xda threads. but it lead to a bootloop as I had flashed a doomloard kernal. I flashed the kernal which was in the zip and all worked fine.